# Compiling C++ program with POSIX AIO lib on Linux

Tags: linux, file, posix, aio

I'm having difficulty with the linker when it comes to compiling a sample program that uses the POSIX aio library (e.g. aio_read(), aio_write(), etc) on Linux.

I'm running Ubuntu with a 2.6 kernel, and have used the apt-get utility to install libaio. But even though I'm linking with the aio library, the compiler still gives me linker errors.

```
root@ubuntu:/home# g++ -L /usr/lib/libaio.a aio.cc -oaio
/tmp/cc5OE58r.o: In function `main':
aio.cc:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `aio_read'
aio.cc:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `aio_error'
aio.cc:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `aio_return'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where are all these aio_x functions actually defined, if not in the library libaio.a?

Comment: Yes.  I also tried

g++ -L /usr/lib64/libaio.a aio.cc -oaio

but got the same linker error

Comment: you aren't linking with the aio library, you simply added "/usr/lib/libaio.a" to the library path.

Answer (score 11):

I also had issues linking against `libaio` in spite of the aio package being correctly installed and the `-lrt` flag being present.

It turned out that placing `-l` flags later (for example, last) in the `gcc` command invocation sometimes fixes this issue. I stumbled upon this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352560/2567285) on Stack Overflow.

I stopped doing this:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -g -o myExe -lrt myExe.c
```

And started doing this:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -g -o myExe myExe.c -lrt
```

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:** according the the man page, libaio.so is not the correct library to link to:

`man aio_read`

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <aio.h>
>
>    int aio_read(struct aiocb *aiocbp);
>
>    Link with -lrt.
> ```

so you should link with this:

```
g++ -lrt aio.cc -o aio
```

The way libraries work with gcc is like this:

-L adds directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.

-l adds a library itself, if the file is named libsomename.so, you just use "-lsomename"

Comment: I have looked into things further, my updated answer should work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libaio-dev
```

Then make sure you specify `-laio` on the link line.

Answer (score 1):

You want `-laio` in order to link to libaio. The argument of `-o` is what you want the compiled executable to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Does **-L** specify the search path and **-l** specifies the actual library?

Comment: It seems that -L specifies the path of the library file, whereas lowercase l searches for the library file using the locations specified in /etc/ld.so.conf, at least on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: No, you got it in the wrong order. -L specifies search paths for libraries(in addition to those found in ld.so.conf) -l specifies a library to link to without the lib prefix. You want -laio

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Evan Teran is correct - it worked when I linked with -lrt.  It seems the aio_x functions are defined in a general POSIX extension library.

Thanks, Evan.