# Error with GLUT compile in ubuntu

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glu

I try to compile some "hello world" glut application:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <GL/glu.h>

#include <GL/glut.h>

GLint Width = 512, Height = 512;

const int CubeSize = 200;

void Display(void)
{
    int left, right, top, bottom;

    left  = (Width - CubeSize) / 2;
    right = left + CubeSize;
    bottom = (Height - CubeSize) / 2;
    top = bottom + CubeSize;

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3ub(255,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glVertex2f(left,bottom);
      glVertex2f(left,top);
      glVertex2f(right,top);
      glVertex2f(right,bottom);
    glEnd();

    glFinish();
}

void Reshape(GLint w, GLint h)
{
    Width = w;
    Height = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, w, 0, h, -1.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
#define ESCAPE '\033'

    if( key == ESCAPE )
        exit(0);
}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(Width, Height);
    glutCreateWindow("Red square example");

    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The compile command is:

```
gcc -lGL -lGLU hw_opengl.cpp -o hw_opengl
```

I've got the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccbnBFHC.o: In function `Display()':
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `glClear'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `glColor3ub'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `glBegin'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `glEnd'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `glFinish'
/tmp/ccbnBFHC.o: In function `Reshape(int, int)':
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `glViewport'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `glOrtho'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
/tmp/ccbnBFHC.o: In function `main':
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `glutInit'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x1f0): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `glutReshapeFunc'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `glutKeyboardFunc'
hw_opengl.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've install GLUT:
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev

There are in /usr/lib:
libglut.a
libglut.so
libglut.so.3
libglut.so.3.9.0

```
locate glu.h
/home/goran/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.0/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/ThirdParty/glu/internal_glu.h
/usr/include/GL/glu.h

/usr/include/GL/gl.h

locate gl.h
...
/usr/include/GL/gl.h
```

What do I do incorrectly?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The GCC linker may scan libraries in the order they are on the command line, which means for you it may scan the libraries first and sees no one using them, and therefore you get the errors. To be sure, place the libraries last on the command line:

```
gcc hw_opengl.cpp -o hw_opengl -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

Comment: Out of interest why would it be that my machine can successfully compile the target without reordering the options? Is this functionality version specific?

Comment: please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353478/installation-of-all-opengl-libraries-for-development-in-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 7):

```
g++ filename.cpp -lGL -lglut -o exfilename
```

and then

```
./exfilename
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because that xlibmesa-gl-dev and xlibmesa-glu-dev do not make soft link to file libGL.so and libGLU.so, so ld cannot find them to link with your code.

Comment: Because ld will look for libGL.so and libGLU.so for the options -lGL and -lGLU, but xlibmesaxxx do not make these two soft links to their own libs.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `-lglut`.

The correct compilation command is `gcc -lGL -lglut -lGLU hw_opengl.cpp -o hw_opengl`

Comment: I try this compile command: gcc -lGL -lglut -lGLU hw_opengl.cpp -o hw_opengl. There are the same errors.

Comment: Hmm that's very odd. I ran the command as you've posted it, and it compiles fine. I ran your program, and I see a red square, as the code indicates. This would indicate that your compiler isn't aware of the library - try running `ldconfig` (as root), or possibly rebooting. What OS are you running?

Comment: I use kubuntu 11.10      $ gcc -lgl -lglut -lglu hw_opengl.cpp -o hw_opengl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglu

Comment: Have you also installed libgl-dev (it may also be called libgl)?

Comment: i've installed xlibmesa-gl-dev and xlibmesa-glu-dev

Comment: I'd suggest installing libgl. I'm unfamiliar with xlibmesa.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgl-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libgl1-mesa-swx11-dev 7.11-0ubuntu3
  libgl1-mesa-dev 7.11-0ubuntu3
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'libgl-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: Go with libgl1-mesa-dev.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 252 not upgraded.

Comment: Hmm. The Ubuntu package manager confuses me at times. Possibly try replacing it with the other package, `libgl1-mesa-swx11-dev`.

Comment: pls see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353478/installation-of-all-opengl-libraries-for-development-in-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you installed `binutils-gold` (Gold linker) or not if not, install it  and if you've already that then remove it and try at terminal,

```
g++ sourcefile.cpp -lglut
```

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ -lglut -lGLU -lGL helloWorld.cpp -o helloWorld
```

`g++`, not `gcc`, for cpp

Comment: Use -std=c++11 if u want to use gcc or add the flag -lstdc++