# undefined reference to glutInit in program that compiled with the same commands just 2 weeks ago

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, compilation, glut

My ubuntu installation recently died and I'm now reconstruction everything.

I have a file that I know recently compiled and worked with the same comment. This is a simple opengl-glut based program.

It compiles with the following line :

```
g++ -lGL -lGLU -lglut -I . *.cp
```

this gives the following error code:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x2de): undefined reference to `glGetDoublev'
/tmp/cc9vO929.o: In function `tbVisuTransform()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2fd): undefined reference to `glMultMatrixd'
/tmp/cc9vO929.o: In function `tbMotionFunc(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f5): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
main.cpp:(.text+0x523): undefined reference to `glRotatef'
main.cpp:(.text+0x52d): undefined reference to `glMultMatrixd'
main.cpp:(.text+0x53c): undefined reference to `glGetDoublev'
main.cpp:(.text+0x649): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
main.cpp:(.text+0x665): undefined reference to `glRotatef'
main.cpp:(.text+0x66f): undefined reference to `glMultMatrixd'
main.cpp:(.text+0x67e): undefined reference to `glGetDoublev'
main.cpp:(.text+0x724): undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
/tmp/cc9vO929.o: In function `tbRotate(double, double, double, double)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x78c): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7b5): undefined reference to `glRotatef'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7bf): undefined reference to `glMultMatrixd'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7ce): undefined reference to `glGetDoublev'
```

this goes on for quite a while. 
I have already installed the build essential and freeglut. 
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev

anybody got any ideas?

I already tried what they said here:
[Error with GLUT compile in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352176/error-with-glut-compile-in-ubuntu)

Note that I upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 if that matters.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/680982).

Comment: Not solving your problem, but you should also consider -Wall -Werror

Comment: But those are about the order however I know for a fact that this line has in the past managed to compile this program. So changing the order should not matter unless some of these libs have suddenly gained dependancy between their current version and the on used a few month ago.

Comment: For the updated question: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826448/linking-libraries-with-gcc-order-of-arguments)

Comment: For one thing, the wildcard `*.cp` will not catch `main.cpp`. So you have not pasted your actual build command here. I would also suggest you put the input file wildcard ***before*** the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ToolchainTransition) and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1833136) links, Ubuntu has changed the default linking strategy in Oneiric (Ubuntu 11.10).

As Oneiric and later versions use the `--as-needed` flag by default, the order of the libraries does matter in Ubuntu.

Comment: Those seem to focus on the difference between pre and after 11.10 while I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 so are these still relevant?

Comment: ok got it should have put *cpp in front of the rest. rather then behind it.